# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreatePolicyVersion operation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, policy

When I used awscli to create a new default policy version, I gave IAM all the permissions. The command to create the policy version is as follows:

```
aws iam create-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::150083650231:policy/erwim-api --policy-document file://NewPolicyVersion.json --set-as-default
```

The following error message is displayed:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreatePolicyVersion operation: User: arn:aws:iam::150083650231:user/erwim-api is not authorized to perform: iam:CreatePolicyVersion on resource: policy arn:aws:iam::150083650231:policy/erwim-api
```

After many tests and tests, and I gave the IAM all the permissions, I still displayed the same error message as above.

How to solve this problem, thank you!
This is the JSON format of my strategy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
            "ec2:DescribeVpnConnections",
            "ec2:GetEbsEncryptionByDefault",
            "ec2:GetCapacityReservationUsage",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumesModifications",
            "ec2:GetHostReservationPurchasePreview",
            "ec2:GetConsoleScreenshot",
            "ec2:GetReservedInstancesExchangeQuote",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:GetConsoleOutput",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:GetPasswordData",
            "ec2:GetLaunchTemplateData",
            "ec2:DescribeScheduledInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeScheduledInstanceAvailability",
            "ec2:GetEbsDefaultKmsKeyId",
            "ec2:DescribeElasticGpus"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "10.10.10.73/32",
                    "10.10.10.153/32",
                    "160.180.22.22/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
            "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy",
            "iam:ListRoleTags",
            "iam:ListServerCertificates",
            "iam:GenerateServiceLastAccessedDetails",
            "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
            "iam:ListSigningCertificates",
            "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
            "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
            "iam:SimulateCustomPolicy",
            "iam:SimulatePrincipalPolicy",
            "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
            "iam:ListRolePolicies",
            "iam:DetachUserPolicy",
            "iam:GetAccountAuthorizationDetails",
            "iam:GetCredentialReport",
            "iam:ListPolicies",
            "iam:GetServerCertificate",
            "iam:GetRole",
            "iam:ListSAMLProviders",
            "iam:GetPolicy",
            "iam:UpdateUser",
            "iam:GetAccessKeyLastUsed",
            "iam:ListEntitiesForPolicy",
            "iam:AttachUserPolicy",
            "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
            "iam:UpdateAccountPasswordPolicy",
            "iam:GetUserPolicy",
            "iam:ListGroupsForUser",
            "iam:GetGroupPolicy",
            "iam:GetOpenIDConnectProvider",
            "iam:GetRolePolicy",
            "iam:GetAccountSummary",
            "iam:GenerateCredentialReport",
            "iam:GetServiceLastAccessedDetailsWithEntities",
            "iam:ListPoliciesGrantingServiceAccess",
            "iam:ListMFADevices",
            "iam:GetServiceLastAccessedDetails",
            "iam:GetGroup",
            "iam:GetContextKeysForPrincipalPolicy",
            "iam:GetOrganizationsAccessReport",
            "iam:GetServiceLinkedRoleDeletionStatus",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfilesForRole",
            "iam:GenerateOrganizationsAccessReport",
            "iam:ListAttachedUserPolicies",
            "iam:ListAttachedGroupPolicies",
            "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
            "iam:GetSAMLProvider",
            "iam:ListAccessKeys",
            "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
            "iam:ListGroupPolicies",
            "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "iam:ListUserPolicies",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
            "iam:CreatePolicy",
            "iam:GetContextKeysForCustomPolicy",
            "iam:ListPolicyVersions",
            "iam:ListOpenIDConnectProviders",
            "iam:PutUserPolicy",
            "iam:ListAccountAliases",
            "iam:ListUsers",
            "iam:GetUser",
            "iam:ListGroups",
            "iam:GetLoginProfile",
            "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion",
            "iam:ListUserTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "10.10.10.73/32",
                    "10.10.10.153/32",
                    "160.180.22.22/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "organizations:ListPoliciesForTarget",
            "organizations:ListRoots",
            "organizations:ListTargetsForPolicy",
            "organizations:DescribeOrganization",
            "organizations:DescribeOrganizationalUnit",
            "organizations:DescribeAccount",
            "organizations:ListParents",
            "organizations:DescribePolicy",
            "organizations:ListChildren",
            "organizations:ListPolicies"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:IpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "10.10.10.73/32",
                    "10.10.10.153/32",
                    "160.180.22.22/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: There can not be any other reason then what is mentioned by the aws error. You need to verify if you have configured correct key and secret on the client. AWS cli uses key and secret configured in environment variables first and if not found then it uses the ones configured via `aws configure` command. Can you share the policy json which is associated with the user?

Comment: Hello, the JSON format configuration of the strategy has been filled in my question, please help me how to solve this!

Comment: In the json `iam:CreatePolicyVersion` has IP restrictions, are you calling the API from the one of the ips mentioned there? Did you try removing the IP restrictions? Are you able to create policy version from aws console with the same user logged in?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. According to your method, I tested it and found that there was a problem with my IP restriction. 
The IP address was not used according to the restriction rules. Thank you again!

Comment: This stack is better fit for these questions - https://devops.stackexchange.com/